# JSONP response in the wrong format

Tags: c#, javascript, jsonp

I am building a JSONP service.

It works if I use `System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory`.

I need to use `System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory` because I want to use URITemplate so I can pass a parameter.  When I switch to this factory, it no longer encodes the response as jsonp.  So I get an error from my javascript which can't figure out what to do with `{"isbn": "~1234567890~"}`

Is this where I need to serialize?  How can I add that to this c# code:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;



namespace Microsoft.Samples.Jsonp
{

    [DataContract]
    public class Response
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string isbn;

    }




    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "JsonpAjaxService")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class CustomerService
    {
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Response GetCustomer()
        {

            string isbns = "";
            /*string line= "";*/
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;  Database=mydb; Uid=peggy; Pwd=dpL'engl3");

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                MySqlDataReader reader;

                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name, obitdate, page FROM dobits";
                /* cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;*/
                cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1; 
                sqlConnection1.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                // Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    isbns = isbns + '~' + reader.GetString(0) + '^' + reader.GetString(1) + '#' + reader.GetString(2);
                }
                sqlConnection1.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\data\exception");
                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            isbns = isbns + "~";
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\data\ReadytoReturn");
            return new Response() { isbn= isbns };
        }

    }
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

 $.getJSON( 'http://192.168.64.180/dobits/service.svc/GetCustomer?callback=?', null,  function(res){


//console.log(res);              // log the result from the callback
//var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
 $.each(res, function(key, val) {

var first = val.indexOf("~");
var next = val.indexOf("~",first+1);

while (next>=0)
{
     $("#homeJacket").append('<p>'+val.substring(first+1,next)+'</p>');

     first=next;
     next=val.indexOf("~",first+1);

}

});

});


});


</script>


<div id="homeJacket">
    <p></p>

</div>
```

The error message I get from firebug is:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
{"isbn":"~1234567890~"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert it to JSONP using the techniques described here:

https://sites.google.com/site/dhtmlexperiments/blogs/crossdomainrestfulserviceinwcf